# Data vault for NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling, data-vault, database, nosql

I have quite a lot of data in JSON format and I would like to build a data warehouse out of them. Since there is a large amount of data and they are semi-structured, I thought to use a document NoSQL database, e.g. MongoDB.

Regarding modelling the data, I thought of using the data vault model.
Is it possible to use the data vault model in NoSQL databases (e.g. MongoDB)?
What are the pros and cons in such a case?

Comment: You said that 'About modelling the data I thought to use the data vault model'. Can you elaborate why you did so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the data vault model is designed for relational databases. The seminal articles defining the data vault concept are still online:

- http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5054/
- http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5155/
- http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5067/
- http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5172/
- http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5285/

IMO, join capabilities are required to implement a data vault, while MongoDB does not support them, so I do not see how such a model could be implemented with MongoDB.

Most NoSQL engines (if not all of them) do not support relational or post-relational database models. It is generally pointless to try to apply relational methodologies to them.